# While loop with nested if statements - C

Tags: c, syntax

I am trying to work on a project to program an iRobot. For this project I have one part where I need this robot to run straight unless a bump sensor is pressed. When different bump sensors are pressed, different things should happen, and then it should continue on moving straight. Here is the code I have so far:

```
while( ReadBumpSensors() == 0) 
{
    drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);

    if ( ReadBumpSensors() == 1 )
        {
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200, 1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        }
    if ( ReadBumpSensors() == 2)
        {
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200,-1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        }
    if ( ReadBumpSensors() == 3)
        {
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200,-1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the robot is only moving straight and not responding to any of the if statements. I feel like it is some type of syntax error but I'm not sure. Any advice?

Comment: As soon as `ReadBumpSensors()` returns anything different than `0`, you will exit the loop, because that's the condition at the beginning. But how does this function work anyway? Does it block until a value is ready? Or returns `0` if there is nothing to return? Does it return a different value on each call (i.e. only reports changes/rising edge)? Does it poll? You need to clarify all these things before attempting to program.

Comment: Do you rather mean while( ReadBumpSensors() != 0)  ?

Comment: When does `ReadBumpSensors` return? And does calling it multiple times wait for new data?

Comment: You might want to read up on `switch`.

Comment: The value 0 means that neither bump sensor is being pressed. I want the robot to move straight indefinitely until one or the other is pressed. When either the right or left sensor is pressed it backs up and turns and then i want it to continue moving indefinitely and repeat the loop.

Comment: What is `RAD_STRAIGHT`?

Comment: It's a variable that holds the value 37382 or something. Basically tells the robot to go straight instead of at an angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your condition of `while` loop is `ReadBumpSensors() == 0`, so The blocks assosiated to `if` statements won't be executed unleess the return value of `ReadBumpSensors()` changes between evaluation of the condition for `while` and `if`.

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
for(;;) /* infinite loop */
{
    switch (ReadBumpSensors())
    {
    case 0:
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    case 1:
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200, 1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    case 2:
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200,-1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    case 3:
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200,-1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update:** the program for case 2 and 3 are same, so you can merge them like this.

```
for(;;) /* infinite loop */
{
    switch (ReadBumpSensors())
    {
    case 0:
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    case 1:
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200, 1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        drive(-200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        delayMs(1000);
        drive(200,-1);
        delayMs(500);
        drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cases for 2 and 3 are the same.

Comment: will the for(;;) continue infinitely? Or is the ";;" just a placeholder for some condition that I can come up with that will always be true?

Comment: Yes, `for(;;)` stands for infinite loop by itself.

Comment: `for(;;)` is the same than `while(1)` that you may also have encountered in C code.

Comment: The last `drive(200, RAD_STRAIGHT);` in each case seems superfluous and potentially harmful - driving without reading sensors first. Also it is a good idea to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Should I take it off then and just allow it to break back to case 0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `ReadBumpSensors()` function does internally, but you will be in this loop only when it returns 0. When this happens, you will always go straight for a bit, and then possibly do something else if the next three calls for `ReadBumpSensors()` will return either 1, 2 or 3.

You could try to change the if-structure from three different if's to if-elseif-elseif -structure, if only one of those operations should be happening in a single loop.